# небольшой вопрос по замыканию

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    var temp;
    return function() {
      this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = a;
      temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp + a;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
```

Каждая кнопка по нажатию на нее должна в спане выводить следующее число Фибоначчи. Где ошибка не понимаю . подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: следующие число для каждой кнопки или следующее для клика на любую кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что ваша функцию, которая была передана `addEventListener`, возвращает в никуда вашу локальную функцию. Что бы к обработчику события привязалась функция, которую вы возвращаеться через `return`, вы должны создать **самовызывающуюсь** (не знаю как правильно написать) функцию.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (function() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    var temp;
    return function() {
      this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = a;
      temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp + a;
    }
  }()));
});
```

```html
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка заключается в том, что переданная функция не вызывается, следовательно замыкание не создается.

Для решения нужно просто вызвать эту функцию, чтобы в качестве обработчика назначилась результирующая функция:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click',
   function() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    var temp;
    return function() {
      this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = a;
      temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp + a;
    }
  }()
  );
});
```

```html
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
<button>Фибоначчи</button><span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то я понял это так, что последовательность чисел должна быть сквозной для всех кнопок.

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var temp;
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = a;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp + a;
  });
});
```

```css
.container span {
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Фибоначчи</button><span>-</span>
  <button>Фибоначчи</button><span>-</span>
  <button>Фибоначчи</button><span>-</span>
</div>
```

Comment: смысл был в том, то каждая кнопка должна быть независима с помощью замыкания